# Why is 'I would love to' so commonly used, and is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, optative-mood

Why is the construction 'I would love to' so commonly used, and is it grammatically correct?

If the  word 'would' cannot be used with state verbs like *love*, *think*, etc, then isn't this technically wrong?

And why is it used so often?

Comment: "I would think it's rude" is very common. *I would love a brownie* is my theme song. Could mean in theory, could mean the future, could be emphasis.

Comment: Why can't "would" be used with stative verbs?

Answer (score 13):

> If the word *would* cannot be used with state verbs like *love, think*, etc, then ...

There's the problem right there. Who in the world ever told you such a silly rule?

As the comments make clear, modal auxiliary verbs like *would* can be used before the infinitive form of any verb at all, quite often another auxiliary verb like *have* or *be*, whether the verb is stative or active.

*I would love to* is a common polite response to an invitation.
It's stronger than *I would like to*, which is stronger than *Yes*.

Comment: Just on your last sentence — I'd disagree that "I would like to" is stronger than "Yes" (in modern usage at least). If I said "I'm having a house-warming next week, will you come?", "I would love to!" sounds like an unequivocal "yes", but "I would like to" sounds like there's some hesitancy attached. More of a "I'll come if I can"

Comment: @anotherdave: Yeah, "I would like to" is usually a prelude to "but".

Comment: Yes, there is a Gricean implicature associated with "I would like to"; this, like _try to open the door_ implicating failure, since if that's all you can say and you would have said "opened" if the attempt had not failed. In this case, if the most you can say is a hypothetical, (because _would_) then probly you're gonna say no and this is being polite. But that's pragmatics, not syntax, not even semantics.

Answer (score 0):

*I would love to* is just shorthand for "I would love to [do what you just suggested/asked/indicated/etc]". It is used so often because it is more efficient than saying "I would love to do that", and much more efficient than repeating verbatim the previous suggestion.

One can argue that this shorthand is technically grammatically incorrect if you believe that splitting infinitives is ungrammatical. But the "rule" against splitting infinitives is [no longer considered](https://www.theguardian.com/science/shortcuts/2017/sep/25/to-boldly-go-split-infinitive-grammatical-error-research) a grammatical touchstone, and it was always one of those just-so grammatical "rules" invented by one or a few authors a couple of hundred years ago to make English function more like Latin.

Even if we assume *I would love to* was at one point considered grammatically incorrect in the same way *to boldly go* was (at least by some), it has become [so ubiquitous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20would%20love%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in the last twenty-five years that nearly every modern native English speaker says it in a consistent way and without a second thought. That is the very definition of grammatical correctness, unless one insists on freezing a language's development in time and rejecting any grammatical innovations as "incorrect", no matter how ubiquitous they become.

Furthermore, as others have suggested, the idea that "would" cannot be combined with stative verbs is a misapprehension. *You would think* is a set-phrase response to someone pointing out a shortfall or a conundrum, and it is not unthinkable that someone might say "I would love again" (e.g., a character in a play who has avoided a romantic relationship, but may be reconsidering their reticence). *Would* is a conditional and subjunctive marker that can be applied to any verb in order to change its aspect -- to make the action dependent on another action, or to make it hypothetical or less certain in some way.